# Cuda Installation: Do I Need the Power9 Stuff?

Tags: cuda

I have a one CPU, one GPU (Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti) Ubuntu 16.04 desktop computer and am in the middle of the Cuda installation.

Do I have to do the activities described in [7.1.2. POWER9 Setup](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#power9-setup) or does this relate to another system setup?

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028338/power9-for-ubuntu16-04/

Comment: No, you won't need it. It refers to the IBM Power 9 system which support  Nvidia's NVLink bus technology. (unless you have this CPU?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028338/power9-for-ubuntu16-04/) supplied in the comment, these Power9 activities are not needed.